# How to get return value from a method whis is already using passed parameters from another method?

Tags: java, parameters

I want to get value returned by `Method2`. `Method2` is using value passed by `Method1`. But this throws the following error.

> Error:(12, 28) java: method Method2 in class parameters cannot be
>   applied to given types;   required: int   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class parameters {
private static int a;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter any number");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
    parameters.Method1(num1);
    int ans= parameters.Method2();

    System.out.println(""+ans);
}

    static void Method1(double num1)
    {
        int a = (int) num1;
        Method2(a);
    }

    static int  Method2(int a)
    {
        return(a *= 3) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int ans = parameters.Method2();` is not valid because you have to pass an `int` argument to this method.

Comment: You seem to miss some of the basics. I suggest you study [Oracle's Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it like that.
Method2 invocation requires an int parameter to be passed.
If at all you need to get returned value of Method2, then:
Option 1. Try to return value from Method1.
Option 2. Make sure you update the static member variable with the computed value.
Here, the static member variable is a, but in Method2, parameter a overshadows member of class.

It looks like you want to update static member variable.

Comment: How to update 'a' and how does it overshadow the member of class?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can do the following.
this will return the answer you are after and also reduce the two-step process.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Parameters {

    private static int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Enter any number");
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       Double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
       int ans = Parameters.Method1(num1);
       System.out.println(""+ans);
    }

    static int Method1(double num1) {
        int a = (int) num1;
        return Method2(a);
    }

    static int  Method2(int a) {
       return (a *= 3);
    }
}
```